# Finding the content size of a tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a custom cell containing a table view inside it. Table View is set to bound to the view which has a height constraint and and I am trying to set the height constraint based on the content size of the table view. But what I am getting is the multiple of estimated row height and number of cells.

Comment: what is content of tableview custom cell?

Comment: the outer (main) custom cell contains two views; top contains a label with height constraint and bottom the table view. The Table view also has a custom cell with dynamic label content.

Comment: i think you can achieve by using stack view.please check .

Comment: i am currently using iOS 8 for my development purpose and i cannot change the version just yet. Also I'm trying to skip the usage of the custom stack views as much as possible.